# LINQ way to count elements in each value of dictionary?

Tags: linq, dictionary, linq-to-objects

I have a `Dictionary<String, String[]>` and I'm hoping for a LINQ way to count up all the strings in the values. Currently I'm using a good ol' fashioned for:

```
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dict.Count; i++) {
    total += dict.ElementAt(i).Value.Length;
}
```

I was thinking of a `Select()` but then I'd have a `IEnumerable<String[]>` or basically a 2D array of strings. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

[Sum<sup>1</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should work for that

```
int total = dict.Sum(d => d.Value.Length);
```

Here is a full working demo you can test in linqpad or a console app if so inclined

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    dict["s"+i] = Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray();
}
int total = dict.Sum(d => d.Value.Length);
Console.Write(total);//100
```

<sub>[1. MSDN: Enumerable.Sum Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)</sub>

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about `Sum()`! I had the wrong approach in mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
total=dict.Select(n=>n.Value.Lenght).Sum();
```

Comment: Travis J was the first.